# Deleting a max element in an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

As you can see I wrote a simple program to find the highest/max element in int array and deleting it from the array and print the remaining array. It giving me an error. I do not want to use STL;

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int findmax(int a[],int size,int max)
{
  for(int k=0;k<size;k++)
  {
    if(a[k]>max)
    max=a[k];
  }
  cout<<"max is :--"<<max<<endl;
  return max;
}

void ddlj(int a[],int size,int z);
{
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
    if (a[i]==z)
    {
      for(int j=i;j<(size -1) ;j++)
      {
        a[j]=a[j+1];
      }
      break;
    }
  }

    for(int x=0;x<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);x++)
    {
      cout<<a[x]<<" ";
    }
}


int main()
{
  int a[]={10,12,15,44,9,8,7,5,1};
  int pos=2 ,z;
  int max=0;
  int size=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
  
  z=findmax(a,size,max);

  ddlj(a,size,z);
  
 return 0;
  
}
```

And the output is

```
 clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
main.cpp:16:1: error: expected unqualified-id
{
^
1 error generated.
compiler exit status 1
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: Remove the **;** at the end of **void ddlj(int a[],int size,int z);** You could use an IDE or any kind of linting plugin to avoid typos like this.

Comment: gotacha !! thanks sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void ddlj(int a[],int size,int z);`
to
`void ddlj(int a[],int size,int z)`

you should install a checker of syntax-error like vs(windows) or ycm(linux).
and welcome to C++

Comment: thank you !! can you suggest me some book or course to get my skills advance?

Comment: Emmm... 《c++ primer》

Comment: geeksforgeeks contains almost everything required by you :)

Comment: @Songmeng oh ok ..!!

Comment: @KL_KISNE_DEKHA_HAI bhai abhi toh wahi use kar raha hu . https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/at-least-two-greater-elements/0/?problemStatus=unsolved&problemType=full&difficulty[]=-2&page=1&query=problemStatusunsolvedproblemTypefulldifficulty[]-2page1 ye wala question solve kar raha hu :)